# how to convert a string to byte array in java

Tags: java, string, arrays, converters

Hi I have the following string

```
   String msg = "9192939495"
```

And i want to create the bellow byte

```
   byte[] texttoprint = {(byte) 0x91, (byte) 0x92,(byte) 0x93,(byte) 0x94,(byte) 0x95}
```

i try this

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    /*String input = "0102FFAB";*/
    byte[] data = new byte[s.length() / 2];

    for( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i+=2)
    {
      data[i/2] = (byte) Integer.decode( "0x" + s.substring( i, i + 2 )  ).byteValue();
    }
    return data;
}
```

but it does not works

Also how can I print texttoprint at eclipse log in order to check if everything is OK?

PS if i send to printer {(byte) 0x91, (byte) 0x92,(byte) 0x93,(byte) 0x94,(byte) 0x95} everything is OK but if i sent the result of hexStringToByteArray nothing happens

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: I sent it to printer but nothing printed...

Comment: how can I print texttoprint at eclipse log in order to check if everything is OK

Comment: @user1081978 try flushing :-) also, you can use `Arrays.toString` to convert `texttoprint` into a text representation

Answer (score 0):

```
static byte[] decode(final String enc) {
  final long val = Long.parseLong(enc, 16);
  final byte[] raw = new byte[] {
    (byte) ((val & 0xff00000000000000L) >> 56),
    (byte) ((val & 0xff000000000000L) >> 48),
    (byte) ((val & 0xff0000000000L) >> 40),
    (byte) ((val & 0xff00000000L) >> 32),
    (byte) ((val & 0xff000000) >> 24),
    (byte) ((val & 0xff0000) >> 16),
    (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >> 8),
    (byte) (val & 0xff)
  };
  final int n = enc.length() >> 1;
  final byte[] trimmed = new byte[n];
  System.arraycopy(raw, 8 - n, trimmed, 0, n);
  return trimmed;
}
```

You can print the values using `Arrays.toString` to convert to text form. To verify they're equal, try using `Arrays.equals`.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(texttoprint, hexStringToByteArray("9192939495"))
    ? "success" : "failure");
```

Comment: sorry but I am java novice and I do not understand how to use the decode... Sorry again